# why is gdb too slow to start on Snow Leopard

Tags: gdb

I use gdb on a MacBook Pro.  It was fine in 'Leopard' but in 'Snow Leopard' it is generally too slow to use.  If I type `gdb <program>` and then `b main` and then `r` it can be more than a minute before the program starts executing.  During this time the CPU activity meter pegs at 100%.  On Leopard it is a few seconds only.  On a virtual Linux machine inside my MacBook it is a few seconds only.  I am not about to switch to Lion.  What can I do here, or where can I go to find help with this?

Answer (score 0):

A friend says to do

```
set inferior-auto-start-dyld off
```